# Check Post Type in custom search to get Woocommerce product attributtes

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, product

I am implementing a woocommerce website. In here I am providing a search bar to search only the products.

```
<form action="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>" method="GET">
    <div class="input-group">
         <input type="search" name="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Products" required>
         <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="products" />
         <div class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The above search code result in `single-product` page. In the single product page's sidebar I have a section that shows the `product attributes` and `attribute terms`.

The following code is for getting the available product sizes in the current page (`product-single`)

```
// get available sizes  for woocommerce sidebar
function getSizes(){
  $sizes = array();
  $codes = array();
  if ( have_posts() ) :
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     echo get_the_title();
     $product = wc_get_product();
     $attributes = $product -> get_attributes('size');
     foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
        foreach ($attribute['options'] as $key => $meta) {
          $meta_array = get_term_meta($meta);

          if($meta_array['label']){
            $temp = array();
            $term = get_term($meta);
            foreach ($term as $key => $value) {
              if($key == 'term_id'){
                $temp['term_id'] = $value;
              }
              if($key == 'name'){
                $temp['name'] = $value;
              }
              $temp['attribute'] = 'size';
            }
            foreach ($meta_array['label'] as $key => $value) {
              if (!in_array($value, $codes)){
                $temp['size'] =  $value;
                array_push($sizes,$temp);
                array_push($codes,$value);
              }
            }
          }
        }
     }
   endwhile; endif; return $sizes;
 }
```

This is the `html` where I print them in `HTML-DOM`,

```
<ul class="w-woo-inner-box">

  <?php $sizes = getaSizes();
      if(!empty($sizes)):
         foreach ($sizes as $key => $size) { ?>
          <li>
            <label class="checkbox inline-block <?php echo checkurlactive($size['attribute'], $size['term_id']); ?>">
                                  <a href="<?php echo generate_filter_url($size['attribute'], $size['term_id']) ?>">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="">
                                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <span><?php echo $size['size']; ?></span>
            </a>
            </label>
          </li>
        <?php }
       else: ?>
            <li class="no-val-found"><span>No sizes found!</span> </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

**PROBLEM :**
That was a huge description. Ok now let's look at the problem, from the above code, when I search a `existing product name` it works fine. But when I search some values from `other post types` There is an `php error` on the page mentioning

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_attributes() on boolean in /..../functions.php on line 482
```

And I tried to debug it and I found that the following loop in `getSizes()` returning the other `post type values`,

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

What is the problem here? How can I avoid searching the other `post type values`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function code you need to check the post type before inside the loop like:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        // Check for "product" post type or continue
        if( 'product' !== get_post_type() ) {
            continue; // jump to next post

        the_title();

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
```

> **This will avoid the error you get** as `$product` will always be a `WC_Product` Object.

---

**Bonus addition:**

Now the [`WC_Product` method `get_attributes()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#524-526) has one argument `$context` that can have 2 values:

- `'view'` (the default value)
- `'edit'` *(to be used in backend)*

> But **NOT:** `$attributes = $product -> get_attributes('size');`

So if you want to get a specific attribute, you will use [`WC_Product` method `get_attribute()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1830-1848) intead that will gives a coma separated string of term names like:

```
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );

        // Loop through 'size' product attribute
        $size_values = $product->get_attribute('size');

        // Convert to an array of term names
        $term_names = (array) explode(', ', $size_values);

        // The product attribute taxonomy (always start with "pa_" + the slug)
        $taxonomy = 'pa_size';

        // Loop through term names
        foreach( $term_names as $term_name ) {
            // Get the WP_Term object (if needed)
            $term = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy );

            $term_id   = $term->term_id;
            $term_slug = $term->slug;
        }
```

Comment: TBH this is a great answer sir. Thank you so much for your valuable time for this question. Here when I check the condition `if( 'product' !== get_post_type() )`  , it works fine but still I have a problem. Here I checked three conditions. 1 - Search values of product type (**works fine**). 2 - Search Other Post Type values ( giving no product message. **works fine**). 3 - Value that no used in any post type (**Now my page is just a white page**, `/?s=qwedsads&post_type=products` my url pattern- still it is a white blank page)

Comment: Current problem is getting the white page. Not it's occurring on blog search. http://dev.wonder.lk/blog/ visit the link and use the sidebar search. Clearly you can see there is a blog `Hello World` and if you search `hello` it says no result found as well as if you search some unavailable values like `dasdasdas` it is just showing a white page

Comment: Both of these searches are really independent. Will it occur on the other search? I will post a question and let you know sir

Comment: @Ramesh You should better ask a new question with your changed code… explaining what you want to get as output (as your actual question is not clear)… Try to give the necessary code to make your issue testable.

Comment: I want your help here sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885253/wordpress-search-bar-result-a-blank-white-page?noredirect=1#comment94664655_53885253